# How to install Dedalus PDE-Solver on Windows?

Tags: windows, pip, conda

I wanted to install the Dedalus package on Windows and use it in Jupyter-Lab. [Here](https://dedalus-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/installation.html) it only talks about linux. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Native installation for Windows is going to entail compiling (with dependencies like OpenMPI). If that doesn't sound exciting - it shouldn't -, consider running Linux under WSL or Docker, and follow the Linux instructions.

Bonus Tip: When setting up the Linux system, consider installing Mambaforge rather than Anaconda/Miniconda. It prioritizes Conda Forge (which is what Dedalus uses) and provides the `mamba` command (fast version of `conda` command).